# cgdb produces noise output symbols to terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cgdb

`cgdb` prints these symbols in terminal: `[32m` `<some string>` `[m`.

It is the "gdb" part of the program that does that. The "cgdb" part(or window, you name it), prints to terminal in colors.
I had installed `cgdb` from the `Linux Mint` packages repository and hoped it will run well.

How can I remove the "noise" output from `cgdb` ?

Comment: You probably want `set style enabled off`.

Comment: @ssbssa no, I want styles stay.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb/issues/224), it should work with the latest cgdb.

Comment: @ssbssa You shoud've mantioned that one has to compile and install it from `git`.

Comment: According to its [NEWS](https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb/blob/master/NEWS#L112), this should work since version 0.7.0.

Comment: @ssbssa I did mention in a question that I installed from repo. No matter github. Nevertheless it is resolved.

Comment: So when you say repository, you don't mean git?

Comment: @ssbssa I will change wording. No I did not mean github. I did mean `linux mint` distro with its repository.

Comment: Hey @user14063792468 , what did the problem turn out to be?

Comment: @Ziv Hello, the problem is that my distro has(had?) old version of a program. I had installed one from `git` and all is well now.